# Multiselect picklist in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to use multi select picklist in lightning.

[image]

Can any one help me with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this requirement by creating custom multi-select picklist:-

1. Create two div one for Available Contacts and other for Selected Contacts.
2. Add two button Removed and Add.
3. Handle the data through wrapper class.

Answer (score 3):

lightning [duallistbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/documentation) base component is pretty cool. You can try it.
However you need to get the list of values from server and to be passed to this component (attribute - options)

Example:

```
<lightning:dualListbox aura:id="selectOptions" name="Select Options" 
                       sourceLabel="Available Cities" 
                       selectedLabel="Selected Cities" 
                       options="{! v.cities }"
                       value="{! v.selectedCities }"                       
                       onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```